# R: convert character to date-time in this form: 2018-07-01 12

Tags: r, datetime

So i have a column like that:

```
2018-07-01 12
2018-07-01 13
2018-07-01 14
```

and I want that date and time form where 2018-01-07 is the date and 12 is 12:00 UTC. I tried the `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` too and the `lubridate` package but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `paste` the two columns and use `as.POSIXct` specifying the formats.

```
df$V3 <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$V1, df$V2), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H', tz = 'UTC')
df$V3
#[1] "2018-07-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-07-01 13:00:00 UTC" "2018-07-01 14:00:00 UTC"
```

If you don't want to remember format use `ymd_h` from `lubridate`

```
df$V3 <- lubridate::ymd_h(paste(df$V1, df$V2))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("2018-07-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-07-01"
), V2 = 12:14), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```